# How to avoid warnings for components registered with document.registerElement

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm looking to use the github [time-elements](https://github.com/github/time-elements) custom web components in a polymer dart application. They work as expected, however I get the warning:

> Warning from polymer (Linter) ... custom element with name "relative-time" not found. See http://goo.gl/5HPeuP#polymer_11 for details.

Following that link explains the problem pretty well:

> This warning can also be a false alarm. For instance, when an element is defined programatically using document.registerElement. In that case the polymer build will not be able to see the definition and will produce this warning.

Is there a recommended approach to making those warnings go away - e.g. by manually registering the elements with dart/polymer?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to get rid of this message but I seem to remember that Polymer.js 0.8 should bring some improvements in this matter (due in the next few months).

Comment: Thanks Günter. Tangential question - do you know if the timeline for polymer-dart is the same as polymer.js? It wouldn't be such a big deal if the warnings were just in the console, but the UI in Dartium is actually marked up with a warnings widget that interferes with my UI.

Comment: Polymer.dart is a bit behind because they build upon Polymer.js. There is a way to disable this widget if this is what you want.

Comment: I think that's the best option at the moment, and I'll keep my eye on the console. Do you have a pointer to the disable mechanism? Thx.

Comment: `transformers:
- polymer:
    ...
    inject_build_logs_in_output: false` (see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21237#c1)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614462

Comment: Works a treat - thanks Günter! Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

- disable the widget

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
    inject_build_logs_in_output: false
```

- disable the Polymer linter

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
   lint: false
```

see also http://dartbug.com/21237