# Is there a way to disable the Polymer error log widget

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The error log widget in the bottom/right corner in the browser is very helpful but sometimes I would be nice if it could be disabled.

see also [How to avoid warnings for components registered with document.registerElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600209)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options

- disable the widget

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
    inject_build_logs_in_output: false
```

- disable the Polymer linter

```yml
transformers:
- polymer:
   lint: false
```

see also http://dartbug.com/21237